# How can I split integers from string line?

Tags: python, split

[image]

How can I split confirmed value, death value and recovered value. I want to add them to different lists. I tried to isdigit method to find value in line. Also I tried split('":'). I thought I can define value after '":'. But these are not working.

https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/us

I added all line to textlist from this page.

I just edited question for other users. My problem solved thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example of the input you're getting and what you want the output to be?

Comment: Please post the text instead of an image.

Comment: For example: confirmed=[1 1 5 5 6 18 47 98 192 359 670 1236 1529]

Comment: How can I add this confirmed numbers to list from string?

Comment: I am glad you fixed this to the original source of the data.  It is a valid data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you gave the valid source of your data it becomes pretty simple:

```
import urllib.request
import json
data = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.covid19api.com/total/dayone/country/turkey"))
confirmed=[]
deaths=[]
recovered=[]
for dataline in data:
    confirmed.append(dataline["Confirmed"])
    deaths.append(dataline["Deaths"])
    recovered.append(dataline["Recovered"])
print ("Confirmed:",confirmed)
print ("Deaths:", deaths)
print ("Recovered:",recovered)
```

Answer (score 1):

The list actually contains a string. You need to parse it and then iterate over it to access the required values from it.

```
import json

main_list = ['.....']
data_points = json.parse(main_list[0])
confirmed = []

for single_data_point in data_points:
   confirmed.append(single_data_point.Confirmed)

print(confirmed)
```

A similar approach can be taken for any other values needed.

Edit:

On a better look at your source, it looks like the initial data is not in the right JSON format to begin with. Some issues I noticed:

1. Each object which has a Country value does not have its closing `}`. This is a bigger issue and needs to be resolved first.
2. The country object starting from the 2nd object has a `'` before the object starting. This should not be the case as well.

I suggest you to look at how you are initially parsing/creating the list.

Comment: Which library is required to use the "Json" command?

Comment: textList=text.split('},')

Comment: How can I use parse in python3 ?

Comment: Please take a look at the sample code above. It is using Python3. You need to import json and you should be set. Please mark this as the right answer if this solves your issue :)